# Javascript filters not working for dynamically inserted HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `.wrapper` with dynamically generated content(tasks). Each `.task` has a data attribute that I'm trying to use for allowing me to make this filterable with preset buttons but it doesn't seem to be working for new incoming data. Only works for the html on the page already on load.

```
<div class="wrapper tasks">
  <div class="task" data-type="urgent">Call Bob</div>
  <div class="task" data-type="very-urgent">Pay Bills</div>
  <div class="task" data-type="very-urgent">Ship Package</div>
  <div class="task" data-type="can-wait">Buy Groceries</div>
</div>

<div class="filters">
  <button id="filter-urgent">Urgent</button>
  <button id="filter-veryurgent">Very Urgent</button>
  <button id="filter-canwait">Can Wait</button>
</div>
```

```
<script>
 var htmlTaskFromExternalAPI = '<div class="task" data-type="very-urgent"></div>';

 function addTask(theTask){ 
   $('.wrapper').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',theTask);
 }

 addTask(htmlTaskFromExternalAPI);
</script>

<script>
 $('#filter-urgent').on( 'click', function(){

   //hide all tasks
   $('.task').hide(); 

   //then show filtered tasks only
   $('.task[data-type="urgent"]').fadeIn();

 });
</script>
```

The problem I'm having is as soon as new tasks come in(from external API in html format with data-type attributes already), all dynamically inserted tasks ignore the filtration.

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler to handle events on elements added after the DOM loads. See the duplicate I marked for more information. Also note that you can improve you JS by making it generic; ie. use classes on the filters along with data attributes to genericise the behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Lfebtgy5/

Comment: Rory, thanks a ton!!